# Eclipse + Velocity = HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, eclipse, velocity

I have huge problems trying to get the simplest Velocity project to run in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna).

I created a dynamic web project running on a Tomcat 7.0 server which has been setup and started from within Eclipse.

I add a simple index.vm to the WebContent folder:

```
<html>
<body>
#set( $foo = "Velocity" )
Hello $foo World!
</body>
<html>
```

I modify the web.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
  version="2.5">

<display-name>Velocity_Test</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.vm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet
</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.vm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

No init-params are used.

The problem seems to be with the jars.

I have tried to copy the two Velocity 1.7 jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder.

I have tried to add the jars as external jars in the java build path properties.

I have tried to add the references to the jars in the deployment assembly.

Yet, no matter what I try the result is always:

HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet

exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.VelocityViewServlet
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any help would be welcome.

Cheers,
Dennis

Comment: Post the complete error log. And think about use a tool like maven to build and manage yours project dependencies.

Comment: I added the exception and root cause to the description.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the **ClassNotFoundException**. Add the dependencies to the project. If you use maven (or another tool to build your projects) is as simple as adding the dependency to the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments on this. Unfortunately I was not able to make the Maven plugin work in the my Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 build. I already spend upwards of ten hours on this issue and cannot afford anymore time. If it is not possible to run the Velocity jars without using Maven, then so be it.

Comment: You can use Velocity without using Maven, but maven makes easy the dependency management. It's a Eclipse problem ? o Maven installation problem ?

Comment: I believe it to be a Maven installation problem. After I install the Maven plugin through the Eclipse interface I get error messages when I try to create a new Maven project or trying to convert an existing project to a Maven project.